# Mapbox, React and Tailwind rendering issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, mapbox

Why am I rendering two maps on page? I can't seem to figure it out.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import mapboxgl from "mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl-csp";
import MapboxWorker from "worker-loader!mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl-csp-worker";
// import "mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css";
// import the mapbox-gl styles so that the map is displayed correctly

mapboxgl.workerClass = MapboxWorker;
mapboxgl.accessToken =
  "Token Here";

function MapboxMap() {
  // this is where the map instance will be stored after initialization
  const mapContainer = useRef();
  const [map, setMap] = useState(undefined);
  const lng = 145.122;
  const lat = -37.89;
  const zoom = 11;

  useEffect(() => {
    // Creating the map
    setMap(
      new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: mapContainer.current,
        style: "mapbox://styles/.....",
        center: [lng, lat],
        zoom: zoom,
        maxZoom: 14,
        minZoom: zoom,
      })
    );
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div
        className="position-absolute top-0 start-0 w-100 h-100"
        ref={mapContainer}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
export default MapboxMap;
```

It is then passed to the index.js app as such

```
import Head from "next/head";
import MapboxMap from "../components/RafMap";
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <MapboxMap />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

It then renders two Maps, one bigger then the other, any ideas as to why. From my understanding I am only calling the mapContainer once?

[image]

Comment: can you share a Minimal, Reproducible code base

Comment: I just imported the commented code on line 4 and it started rendering fine for me.